# don't use object as a type

Tags: typescript, eslint, tslint

I am getting the lint error:

> don't use object as a type

When I use object as a type, example follows:

```
export const myFunc = (obj: object): string => {
  return obj.toString()
}
```

Any idea what type I should give to an object with unknown properties?

If it helps the object in question is NOT an array (which I know is strictly an object in JS)

Thanks in advance

Comment: In this case such linter rule is useless..

Comment: obviously, the whole function is useless - its just an example - thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve this error 'don't use object as a type'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64962822/how-can-i-solve-this-error-dont-use-object-as-a-type)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a few different ways to do this. Generally I feel the need for this is a bit of an anti-pattern.

But I would probably go for `Record<string, any>`, if that covers it for you.

Answer (score 8):

I think that the best approach here is to use generic:

```js
export const myFunc = <T extends { toString: () => string }>(obj: T): string => {
    return obj.toString()
}

myFunc(2) // no error
myFunc({}) // no error
```

If you want restrict your arguments to only object, then yes, @Evert's solution is Ok.
But for the sake of type safety it is better to use `unknown` instead of `any`:

```js
Record<string, unknown>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a concrete example of why the linter rule advices against using the `object` type:

```
function foo(obj: object) {
    for (const key in obj) {
        const val = obj[key]; // Compilation error: type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'
    }
}

function bar(obj: { [key: string]: unknown }) {
    for (const key in obj) {
        const val = obj[key]; // works :)
    }
}
```