# Why does interface lose its properties when one property is defined with index signatures?

Tags: typescript, trpc.io

Below is the example code of my issue. I'm using tRPC and Zod in the example.

```
import { initTRPC, inferRouterOutputs } from '@trpc/server';
import { z } from "zod";
const t = initTRPC.create();
const { router, procedure } = t;

interface ITest {
  [key: string]: object | unknown;
  prop: string;
}

export const appRouter = router({
  foo: procedure.input(z.undefined()).query(() => {
    let test: ITest = { prop: "test" };

    return test;
  }),
});

export type AppRouter = typeof appRouter;

type bar = inferRouterOutputs<AppRouter>["foo"];
//   ^?
// type bar = { [x: string]: never; [x: number]: never; }
// expected: ITest
```

Here, bar is typed as

```
type bar = {
    [x: string]: never;
    [x: number]: never;
}
```

This results in a type mismatch, as the query data is no longer typed as `ITest` nor has the `prop` property, contrary to the actual data. Is this default TypeScript behavior or tRPC? How do I work around this problem?

Comment: . @SimHo seems like trpc don't handle `unknown`s and multiple indexes properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template function `` is in the file `types.d.ts`, and is in a section labeled as **"deprecated will be removed in next major as it's v9 stuff"**.

```
/**
 * @deprecated will be removed in next major as it's v9 stuff
 */
...
export type inferSubscriptionOutput<
  TRouter extends AnyRouter,
  TPath extends string & keyof TRouter["_def"]["subscriptions"]
> = inferObservableValue<
  inferProcedureOutput<TRouter["_def"]["subscriptions"][TPath]>
>;
export type inferProcedureClientError<TProcedure extends AnyProcedure> =
  inferProcedureParams<TProcedure>["_config"]["errorShape"];
type GetInferenceHelpers<
  TType extends "input" | "output",
  TRouter extends AnyRouter
> = {
  [TKey in keyof TRouter["_def"]["record"]]: TRouter["_def"]["record"][TKey] extends infer TRouterOrProcedure
    ? TRouterOrProcedure extends AnyRouter
      ? GetInferenceHelpers<TType, TRouterOrProcedure>
      : TRouterOrProcedure extends AnyProcedure
      ? TType extends "input"
        ? inferProcedureInput<TRouterOrProcedure>
        : inferTransformedProcedureOutput<TRouterOrProcedure>
      : never
    : never;
};
export type inferRouterInputs<TRouter extends AnyRouter> = GetInferenceHelpers<
  "input",
  TRouter
>;
export type inferRouterOutputs<TRouter extends AnyRouter> = GetInferenceHelpers<
  "output",
  TRouter
>;
```

This is not the full listing - the definition further calls other template conditional functions not shown above.

**The authors didn't test for all cases, including the case using an generic index key.  That is the answer.**

As a separate comment, TypeScipt template function are qualitatively fragile and complex template functions are difficult to debug.  In fact, template functions will silently return a wrong a answer if the computation gets too deep - although that may not have happened here. It could just have failed any of the `extends`conditions and hit a `never`.

That may be why the template function you are asking about -`inferRouterOutputs` - is being deprecated.

---

Previous answer can be seen by viewing edit history.

Comment: I received multiple answers (which they deleted for some reason) with conflicting reasons. Some people think it's default Typescript behavior and the type needs to be adjusted; some believe it's a bug in tRPC and that the type should be handled correctly. 

Could you explain how the behavior of `object|unknown` relates with index signatures? Why would tRPC convert the value to `never` (assuming tRPC isn't the problem here)?

Comment: Did changing from `object | unknown` to `unknow` or `any` make a difference?

Comment: Updated answer after reviewing source.

Comment: Changing `unknown` to `any` does solve the issue. However, that's not an option as the community around the library with the problematic types [decided it was better for typesafety](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-node/issues/491). 

The actual situation is with tRPC client query functions returning the wrong types, not exactly with `inferRouterOutputs`; I used it because their result was identical, but now I see that I might have misled you by doing so. My bad.

Still, your answer suggests that it is most probably a bug in tRPC and not TypeScript. Thanks.

Comment: @SimHoZebs - Thanks for delivering on this slippery problem.  Not wanting to change the answer that was already selected, I added another answer with additional notes.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional information that is highly relevant to posted question, but might or might not be related to the observed behavior:

**Note1:**

```
type X = object | unknown; // tooltip shows "type X = unknown"
type Y = object | any; // tooltip shows "type Y = any"
```

[TypeScriptPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UD2AjAVhAxsKAfKArgHYDWRSA7kQNxQD0dUwSSANsAJZhQDOAFpR5QARKEiwEhUuSrCAUGOgBNSagzY8UAIZEQtBkxbsuvARSGjwyyTpDy5coA)

`object|unknown` is equivalent to `unknown` (see [TypeScript Documentation "New Unknown Top Type"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type)). That means writing `object|unknown` *should* be no different than writing `unknown`. However, there *might* be side effects in TypeScript template functions where is does make a difference.

Likewise `object|any` is equivalent to `any`.

**Note2**
Although it is probably not related to your issue -
Use of object instead of `{[x:string]:unknown}` or `{[x:string]:any}` may have unexpected side effects, as shown in the following code:

```
function foo(obj: object) {
    for (const key in obj) {
        const val = obj[key]; // Compilation error: type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'
    }
}

function bar(obj: { [key: string]: unknown }) {
    for (const key in obj) {
        const val = obj[key]; // works :)
    }
}
```

See [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66575880/4376643).

**Note3**

I modified the code in [this working online `trpc` site](https://stackblitz.com/github/trpc/trpc/tree/main/examples/minimal?file=server%2Findex.ts&file=client%2Findex.ts&view=editor) to copy in your in addition, changing a any variable names that collided.

I found that the result of using

```
interface ITest {
  [key: string]: object | unknown;
  prop: string;
```

was

```
"bar = {}"
```

The type `{}` in Typescript is actually not an object with no properties - it is instead a special case treated as `{ [x:string]:any }`.

So at least in that test in that trpc online environment, the `prop:string` property was effectively converted to `prop: any`.

I mention this because you said in your comment that

```
interface ITest {
  [key: string]: any;
  prop: string;
}
```

worked for you.